# Upper bound on non-square matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose the following non-square matrices, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 6}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{6 \times 2}$ and a vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$.

What kind of upper bound can I put on the following multiplication;

$$
WBu,
$$

where $u$ has the following bounds: $u_{\text{min}} \leq u \leq u_{\text{max}}$. For a quadratic form ($u^TWBu$), I know this can be upper bounded by $\lambda_{\text{max}} (WB) \|u\|^2$, where $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $WB$ if it is a semi positive definite matrix. For this non quadratic form I'm looking for a similar upper bound

Matrix $B$ is known and has no special properties. Matrix $W$ is not known and is free to be chosen.

(Personally, I do not come from a strong mathematical background, my apologies for any trivial writing mistakes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One such upper bound is
$$
WBu \leq \|WB\| \cdot \|u\|,
$$
where $\|WB\|$ denotes the "induced 2-norm" of $WB$, which in this case is simply equal to the norm of the row-vector $WB$. More general, $\|M\|$ is the maximal singular value of $M$.

Comment: Your answer starts from a quadratic form ($u^T WU u$). In my case I have only $uWB$. How can I use your answer for this? Because $WBu$ returns a scalar whereas your answer does not

Comment: I had a mistake, see my edit

Comment: Thank you for your answer